# sql for a table with two foreign keys to same table causing Cartesian product

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am fairly new to SQL and I am stuck with this query. So I have a table that contains two foreign keys to the same table. The result I require just won't show up using joins. I have created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e790a/4/0) here

Although the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e790a/4/0) is on MySQL, I have the same problem on Oracle.

The two tables look like this:

Table `wedding`

```
wedding_id|civil_union_side_a|civil_union_side_b 
________________________________________________
1         |Smith             |Jones
```

Table `guest`

```
guest_side|guest_name
_____________________
Smith     |John
Smith     |Jill
Smith     |Mark
Jones     |Jane
Jones     |David
Jones     |Mel
```

Now the result that I require should look like this:

```
wedding_id|civil_union_side_a|civil_union_side_b|guest_side|guest_name
_______________________________________________________________________
1         |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |John
1         |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |Jill
1         |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |Mark
1         |Smith             |Jones             |Jones     |Jane
1         |Smith             |Jones             |Jones     |David
1         |Smith             |Jones             |Jones     |Mel
```

which i basically achieved using a `union:`

```
select * 
from wedding 
     inner join guest guest_side_a
on wedding.civil_union_side_a = guest_side_a.guest_side 

union all

select * 
    from wedding 
inner join guest guest_side_b
on wedding.civil_union_side_b = guest_side_b.guest_side
```

However, when I try to join the tables, I get a Cartesian Product. Here is the query I have:

```
select * 
from wedding wedding
      inner join guest guest_side_a
on wedding.civil_union_side_a = guest_side_a.guest_side
      inner join guest guest_side_b
on wedding.civil_union_side_b = guest_side_b.guest_side;
```

and the incorrect result I get (9 Rows instead of 6):

```
wedding_id|civil_union_side_a|civil_union_side_b|guest_side|guest_name|guest_side1|guest_name1
_______________________________________________________________________________________________
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |John      |Jones       |Jane
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |Jill      |Jones       |Jane
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |Mark      |Jones       |Jane
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |John     |Jones        |David
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |Jill     |Jones        |David
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith     |Mark      |Jones       |David
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith      |John     |Jones       |Mel
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith      |Jill     |Jones       |Mel
1        |Smith             |Jones             |Smith      |Mark     |Jones       |Mel
```

Is there a way to get the desired result with a `join` and without a `union` ?

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Oracle here? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh I had this problem on both databases as I have mentioned in the question. This is fairly generic sql that would apply to most RDBMS's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's generally not recommended to use `*` in the `SELECT` list, the following should at least give you an example:

```
SELECT wedding.*, guest.*
FROM guest
RIGHT JOIN wedding
    ON guest.guest_side = civil_union_side_a
    OR guest.guest_side = civil_union_side_b;
```